# Updating python module varaibles from another python module

Tags: python

I need to update the python module's variable values from another python module.
Values need to be updated permanently to the module, not just for run-time.
So need to update the module file. How should I do that?

**VersionInfo.py** file has variables with some default values.
This file should be updated while executing another python file **ReleaseVersion.py**.

**VersionInfo.py**

```
__app__ = 'MyApp'
__appName__ = 'My Classic Application'
__version__ = 0.1
__updater__ = 'Kumaresan Lakshmanan'
__updatedOn__ = '2017-08-29'

#Other Lookups
versionStr = "v%s" % __version__
versionInfo ='%s (%s)' % (versionStr, __updatedOn__)
loggerName = __app__
stdLogFile = __app__ + '_log.txt'
errorLogFile = __app__ + '_error.txt'
```

**ReleaseVersion.py**

```
import VersionInfo

newVersion = VersionInfo.__version__
newVersion += .1
updatedOn = currentDate()
updater = 'Lakshmanan'

VersionInfo.__version__ = newVersion
VersionInfo.__updater__ = updater
VersionInfo.__updatedOn__ = getCurrentDate()

def updateVersionInfo():
    # i m planning to go by followin step, need some better logic...
    # 1. open versioninfo.py file into a str...
    # 2. in str, search for old values and replace with new values
    # 3. write back the str to versioninfo.py file
    # Any other better logic i can do?

updateVersionInfo()
```

Comment: Instead of trying to modify the existing file, why nor rewrite it entirely with the new values?

Answer (score 0):

I do realize this is a very old question but maybe someone else has a question similar to this. You could attempt to make sort of a fake database with text files. Since python can easily write and read to text files, it would be very simple. You can create something such as

```
VersionInfo.txt::
__app__ = 'MyApp'
__appName__ = 'My Classic Application'
__version__ = 0.1
__updater__ = 'Kumaresan Lakshmanan'
__updatedOn__ = '2017-08-29'
```

And then import the file and split each line on the equal sign. This way you have a readable text file with all the information needed.